# how to enable usim in aosp

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-6p

I try enable "usim" in AOSP.

Many answers flashing vender.img or download binary driver, but it's not working.

So... How to enable usim?

fix AOSP code? or flashing another .img?

---

Here my case...

Device: nexus6P

AOSP: 6.0.1_r62 MTC20F

USIM: Insert card

WIFI: Working

Flashing vendor.img and radio.img: Done

Modify AOSP Code: Not yet

---

In device settings app...

SIM status: Not available

IMEI information: Unknown

Status bar: No SIM